# Opening multiple folders (with excel files) with python

Tags: python, excel, directory

I am trying to open several directories and read the data inside of each file inside each directory. So far, I am able to get the four directories. I want to save the data in an array called 'Files' so I can then reference it kind of like this:

```
Frequency[filenumber]    = Files[filenumber]['Frequency (GHz)']
```

this is what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os

root=Tk()
root.withdraw() #closes tkinter window pop-up
titles=['Choose 16W 2-18 GHz','Choose 20W 6-18 GHz','Choose 30W 2-18 GHz','Choose 50W 8-12 GHz']


dirs = []
counter=0

while counter < 4:
    dirselect = filedialog.Directory(parent=root,title=titles[counter])
    d = dirselect.show()
    if not d: break
    dirs.append(d)
    counter=counter+1
print('Directories: ',dirs) 
dirs[:]=[x+'/' for x in dirs]
length=len(dirs)
Files=[None]*length


for c in range(0,length): #directory
    for s in os.listdir(dirs[c]): #files
        Files[c].append(pd.read_excel(dirs[c]+s))
```

And this is giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: You have `Files=[None]*length` (a list of `None`), so `Files[c]` will be `None`. The error is pretty clear. You probably wanted `Files=[[]]*length` (a list of empty lists).

Comment: @Galen

You're right. I initialized it wrong

Comment: @Galen
Actually... When I index a path (File[0]) It gives me the data for all of the folders. I would like to initiate my array in a way that I can index each path and folder. Example.... File[0][0] would index the first file in the first directory and File[0] would index the first path selected.That way, I would be able to to access the information in that file by doing File[0][0]['Frequency (GHz)'] etc.

Comment: got it. Files = [[] for x in range(length)] #list of files